# Spring Security bloqueia pedidos POST apesar das configurações

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

Estou a desenvolver uma API REST baseada no Spring Boot (`spring-boot-starter-web`) onde utilizo o Spring Security (`spring-security-core` e `spring-security-config`) para configurar a proteção dos diferentes *endpoints*.

A autenticação é feita com base numa base de dados local onde estão registados os utilizadores com dois tipos de *roles* diferentes: `ADMIN` e `USER`. Os `USER` devem conseguir fazer `GET` a todos os pontos da API e `POST` aos *endpoints* com base em `routeA`. Os `ADMIN` devem conseguir fazer o mesmo que os `USER` e ainda fazer `POST` e `DELETE` aos *endpoints* com base em `routeB`.

Porém o comportamento que eu estou a ter é que consigo fazer `GET` a qualquer endpoint mas `POST` resulta em `HTTP 403 Forbidden` quer com utilizadores que tenham o *role* `ADMIN` quer `USER`, que não é o esperado com base na minha `SecurityConfiguration`.

Alguma ideia do que me esteja a escapar?

---

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Using database as the authentication provider.");
        builder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and().
            authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/routeA/*").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/routeB/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                               .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/routeB/*").hasRole("ADMIN").and().
            requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache()).and().
            httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and().
            cors();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD", "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

**RouteBController .java**

```
@RestController
public class RouteBController {

    static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RouteBController.class);

    public RouteBController() { }

    @RequestMapping(value = "routeB", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getStuff() {
        return "Got a hello world!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "routeB", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String postStuff() {
        return "Posted a hello world!";
    }

}
```

**RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint.java**

```
@Component
public class RESTAuthenticationEntryPoint extends BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        setRealmName("AppNameHere");
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }
}
```

Comment: Experimente desabilitar o [CSRF](https://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/).

Comment: Obrigado @StatelessDev, isso realmente fez com que já não fosse retornado `403`! Qualquer das formas tanto o utilizador `USER` como `ADMIN` agora conseguem fazer `POST`. Alguma ideia?

Comment: Mas isso é suposto por sua aplicação, correto? Ou você se refere à rota B?

Comment: Para a `RouteA` ambos devem conseguir fazer `POST`, já para a `RouteB` só utilizadores com papel de administrador é que devem conseguir

Comment: O problema era a expressão que eu estava a usar no `antmatcher(HttpMethod, String)` que devia de ser `/routeB/**` em vez de `/routeB/*`. @StatelessDev por favor responda à pergunta para poder marcar a sua ajuda como resposta :)

Comment: Resposta criada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve desabilitar o CSRF:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        // ...
        .csrf().disable();
}
```